# How can I allow multiple subnet in the apache Vhost file?

Tags: linux, apache, virtualhost

im trying to allow a website just for a couple subnets in the vhost file. What is the best way to do it?

So i want to avoid to write down every single subnet from 10.10.56 to 10.10.122..

```
    #Order allow,deny
    #allow from all
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 10.10.56
    Allow from 10.10.57
    Allow from 10.10.58
    Allow from 10.10.59
    Allow from 10.10.60
    Allow from 10.10.
    Allow from 10.10.122
```

Can i just write something like 10.10.56-122 ?

thanks in advance

Comment: You can just note down a partial address, as far as I know, which offers you left aligned wildcard functionality. But that should be easy to find out by reading the documentation. What does it say?